# How to concat the last string dynamically i.e "201010" from table affiliate_earnings_breakdown_201010

Tags: java, sql, mysql

How  to concat the last string dynamically i.e "201010" from table affiliate_breakdown_201010.

Since there are many similar tables to be retrieved dynamically as I could not hard code the table name, because only last string differs and rest of table string is common for all tables.

I want to retrieve the count of records from last 90 days as shown below:

```
String queryString = "select count(*) from ("+

" (select a.keyword_id  from affiliate_breakdown_201010 a where a.keyword_id = "+keywordId+" and a.summary_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL "+days+" DAY) and CURDATE())"+ 

" union all"+ 

" (select i.keyword_id  from affiliate_breakdown_201009 i where i.keyword_id = "+keywordId+" and i.summary_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL "+days+" DAY) and CURDATE())"+

" union all"+ 

"(select i.keyword_id  from affiliate_breakdown_201008 i where i.keyword_id = "+keywordId+" and i.summary_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL "+days+" DAY) and CURDATE())"+

" ) as s";
```

Answer (score 0):

First of: don't inject your `keywordId` into your SQL statement like that, as it can easily lead to a [SQL Injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use a [`PreparedStatement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead.

Unfortunately the `PreparedStatement` doesn't work for table names (mostly because databases don't usually contain dynamic table names, it's rather unusual to do stuff like you have). In this case you need to use "normal" string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

The concatenation of java strings is done using operator +. You already did this several times in your statement.

So, implement loop that takes the date (month) and creates the query. Something like the following:

```
int year = 2010;
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("select count(*) from (");
for (int i = 1;  i <=12;  i++) {
    String suffix = "" + year + (month < 10 ? "0" : "") +  month;
    String tableName = "affiliate_earnings_breakdown_" + suffix;
    String alias = "a" + i;
    query.append("(select a.keyword_id  from " + tableName + " " + alias + " where a.keyword_id = "+keywordId+" and a.summary_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL "+days+" DAY) and CURDATE())");
    if (i < 12) {
        query.append(" union all");
    }
}

query.append(") as s");
```

Please note that I have not verified that the code really works and create correct SQL statement. I leave this task for you. I believe that this example is a good start that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** You need 3 unions for 4 months (current + 3 prior to get 90 days).

*This could probably be optimized!*

```
// import java.util.Calendar;
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int cur = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) * 100 + cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
cal = cal.add(Calendar.MONTH,-1);
int cur_minus_1 = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) * 100 + cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
cal = cal.add(Calendar.MONTH,-1);
int cur_minus_2 = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) * 100 + cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
cal = cal.add(Calendar.MONTH,-1);
int cur_minus_3 = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) * 100 + cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;

String queryString = "select count(*) from ("+

" (select a.keyword_id  from affiliate_breakdown_" + cur + " a where a.keyword_id = "+keywordId+" and a.summary_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL "+days+" DAY) and CURDATE())"+ 

" union all"+ 

" (select i.keyword_id  from affiliate_breakdown_" + cur_minus_1 + " i where i.keyword_id = "+keywordId+" and i.summary_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL "+days+" DAY) and CURDATE())"+

" union all"+ 

"(select i.keyword_id  from affiliate_breakdown_" + cur_minus_2 + " i where i.keyword_id = "+keywordId+" and i.summary_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL "+days+" DAY) and CURDATE())"+

" union all"+ 

"(select i.keyword_id  from affiliate_breakdown_" + cur_minus_3 + " i where i.keyword_id = "+keywordId+" and i.summary_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL "+days+" DAY) and CURDATE())"+

" ) as s";
```